# Best subset selection

Tags: feature-selection, model

My statistical learning text claims that for best subset selection, 2^p total models must be fit through regression if for p covariates, we fit p choose k models at each k, k = 1,...,p.  I interpret this mathematically as 2^p = p choose 1 + ... + p choose k.  Why 2^p models?

Comment: I hope that the text explains why this is an invalid statistical procedure.

Comment: They claim it becomes computationally unreasonable after p = 40.

Comment: Computational reasonableness has nothing to do with statistical validity.  The approach biases $\hat{\beta}, \sigma, R^{2}, P$, and standard errors, overfits, hurts predictive accuracy, and doesn't handle collinearity properly.  I don't know what else could go wrong.

Answer (score 7):

1) For each of p covariates, think of something indicating whether it's either included as a predictor (1) or it isn't (0). There are two possibilities of the indicator for each of $p$ predictors.

That is, there are 2 x 2 x 2 ... x 2 models (where there are p terms)

2) You're almost correct, in fact it's:

$$\sum_{i=0}^p {p\choose i} = 2^p$$

e.g. ${2\choose 0} + {2\choose 1} + {2\choose 2} = 1 + 2 + 1 = 2^2$

As for *why* that's true, think of the [binomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) of $(1+1)^p$.